# How to set custom time filters for strategy execution on tradingview

Tags: pine-script

How do I create a strategy that executes only in a custom time window? For example a strategy can only trade between 0830 and 1130. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
time_int = input("0830-1130", "Time interval", input.session) //trading time

in_time_int = time(timeframe.period, time_int) // series of boolean values that are equal to true on bars within given time interval
```